# Magento 2.0 rollback to Magento 1.9x - question about attributes

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, category, attributes, attribute-set

Being a new magento "developer" (use quotes because honestly, I can barely navigate the admin let alone build this site properly!) I still have tons to learn. Recently tried to procure cheap hosting for a test site, and realized that the proper version of MySQL is still very uncommon and have not found hosting cheap enough that allows me to upgrade the MySQL version. That said, the plan now is to roll back to version 1.9.x so we can have a test host that mirrors the live host.

The main problem I am concerned about is not importing the products, but the categories, attributes and attribute sets. There are so many tables in Magento and I don't know which ones I need to export from the live version (which is currently running 2.x) and import to the new version (which will be 1.9.x)

Does anybody know which tables I need to port over after I install a fresh 1.9.x version and if there are any differences in the table structure to make sure I have all categories, attributes, and attribute sets ready on the new site so I can properly import all the products? THANKS IN ADVANCE and sorry if this question is too newbie!